# How to create a rolling ball with Python in Blender?

Tags: video, linux, blender

My friend told me that you could create games in blender and it has an game engine in it. Now I want to do some simple things with blender such as rolling ball, the topic now in this question.

[image]

Basically, my problem contain

**Problems**

> 1. a learning problem and reference-request.
> 2. I am using DVO -layout where many keys such as " and ' are broken -- and many hotkeys are broken (things are apparently hard-coded to QWE -layout).
> 3. I find it hard to find help about using python inside Blender, besides broken window-paste-board in X, lack of TAB as auto-completion
>      and lack of good examples.

**Helper questions**

> 1. what kind of modules and functions does it have to edit and tune the Blender -objects?
> 2. How can I do a rolling ball such as from (-500,0) to (50,0) with 7-turns in 7 seconds?
> 3. Is it possible to handle basic operations in the Python console?
> 4. Where can I find Blender-Python code to see examples?
> 5. How can I render and open up the render-result to a new window with the console?

Answer (score 2):

**Answers**

> > I. a learning problem and reference-request.
>
> Please, see very good examples [here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Extensions/Python/Console). The code can also become
>   useful
>   [here](https://svn.blender.org/svnroot/bf-blender/branches/apricot/release/scripts/console.py). Good tutorial video [here](http://blip.tv/pycon-us-videos-2009-2010-2011/pycon-2011-using-blender-s-new-bpy-python-api-4898905). Main docs [here](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Extensions/Python).
>
> > II. I am using DVO -layout where many keys such as " and ' are broken -- and many hotkeys are broken (things are apparently
> >     hard-coded to QWE -layout).
>
> `Press AltGr + <quote key>` or select no-dead-key-keyboard, keys such
>   as shift-space tend to interrupt with Blender -keys.
>
> > III. I find it hard to find help about using python inside Blender, besides broken window-paste-board in X, lack of TAB as auto-completion
> >     and lack of good examples.
>
> The key is auto-completion (not with TAB for some odd reason but
>   CTRL+SPACE) and the key command is `$ bpy`. I haven't yet found a solution for the clipboard, investigating.
>
> > **Example 1: specify a ball to origin with Python in Blender**
> >
> > Select your ball in 3D mode and then:
> >
> > ```
> > $ bpy.context.object.location.xyz=[0,0,0]
> > ```
> >
> > so you have your ball in origin.

**Animation**

It is not easy to explain this so some puzzles while also working on it.

> **Puzze 0: show the details about things**
>
> ```
> >>> for object in bpy.data.objects: 
>          print(object.name + " is at location " + str(object.location))
> ```
>
> **Puzzle 1: create cubes ([source](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Extensions/Python/Console))**
>
> ```
>  >>> mylayers = [False]*20
>  >>> mylayers[0] = True
>  >>> add_cube = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add
>  >>> for index in range(0, 5):
>  ...     add_cube(location=(index*3, 0, 0), layers=mylayers)
> ```
>
> **Puzzle 2: perhaps useful things**
>
> ```
> >>> bpy.context.object.animation_
> data
> data_clear(
> data_create(
> visualisation
> ```

**Related Questions**

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10972637/how-can-i-access-bpy-in-standard-python-console-bpy-is-the-blender-python-thin/10973302#10973302
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3924294/blender-python-scripting-tutorials?rq=1